# Getting error while taking the Screenshots using fastlane

Tags: android, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I am getting the error while capturing the screenshots using the `fastlane`

Code in my **androidTest**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        assertEquals("com.tcc.gstknowledge", appContext.getPackageName());
    }

    @ClassRule
    public static final LocaleTestRule localeTestRule = new LocaleTestRule();

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testTakeScreenshot() {
        Screengrab.setDefaultScreenshotStrategy(new UiAutomatorScreenshotStrategy());
        Screengrab.screenshot("before_button_click");

        // Your custom onView...
        onView(withId(R.id.activity_btn1)).perform(click());

        Screengrab.screenshot("after_button_click");
    }
}
```

I have a lane file with this code.

```
 lane :screenshots do
    capture_android_screenshots
    #upload_to_play_store
  end

  desc "assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest"
  lane :assembleScreengrab do
    gradle(task: "assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest")
  end
```

I am trying to execute the following commands in the terminal inside my project folder.

1. `fastlane assembleScreengrab` for the creating the debug build and test debug build.
2. `fastlane screenshots` for the capturing the Screenshots.

But when i am trying to capture screenshot by executing the `fastlane screenshots` it will give me the following error of the

> INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1

Detailed Error Screenshot :-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error and the solution is add this line in your build.gradle file i have an old project so it will not added in that particular project but now days it will come by default when we are creating the android project.

```
defaultConfig {
   ....
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   ....
}
```